# How to scroll to a position above a target section using in-page HTML links

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I know how to jump to a section on a page using:

```
<a href="#link">Link</a>`
<a name="Link">
```

My question is: how can I make the jump location be 50px up from the default?

Basically make it so when I jump to the section, it doesn't appear exactly at the top of the browser, but allows for some buffer room.

Comment: Exactly 50px? You will need to use Javascript. You could simply place the anchor name above where you want to be (roughly 5 `<br>`s)

Comment: You just need to link to an element 50px above what you want the user to see!

Comment: You do not *need* to use JavaScript, nor would I advocate adding `<br>` elements for whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

You could add `padding-top: 50px;` to your target(s), with a possible unintended side-effect of always having `50px` of space above your target(s).

Example:

HTML:

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>
<div style="height:1000px"><!-- create some whitespace for demo purposes --></div>

<h1 id="test">Target</h1>
<div style="height:1000px"><!-- create some whitespace for demo purposes --></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test { padding-top: 50px; }
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/A8ucv/)

Answer (score 3):

For clean code that solves your problem, use CSS "before":

```
<style>
#link:before{
padding-top:50px;display:block;content:"";
}
</style>

<a href="#link">Link</a>
<div id="link">content</div>
```

Comment: actually I lied a little. The code you provided does work, although it makes the element a block and therefore provides the 50px padding on both the top and the bottom. Is there a way to make it so the padding only appears on the top ?

Comment: hopefully you get the notification.

Comment: I wrote "padding-top", so it should work...try with display:inline-block; I may work. If it's fine, mark the answer so users will know that it works...

Comment: I have tried both the suggestions you made, plus just about every property for display and padding. I have even tried to manually set the padding with -- padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px; Yet the problem still remains. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution to be the most effective as it allows for you to add some padding above your target section, without adding spacing between your elements.

Add an invisible `<div>` above your element, then move it upwards by adjusting the relative position.

```
<style>
#section{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px; 
    top: -90px; /* Adjust this */
}
</style>

<div id="#section"></div> 
<div>content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using some CSS like this

HTML

```
<a name="Link" class="link1">
```

CSS

```
.link1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hyperlink that puts the cursor in a form field on the page by adding the relevant name of the field. Just add the sharp character before it.

`http://hyperlink#sms_recipient`

This link goes to the page and puts the focus on the mobile phone number field. The visitor can immediately type the number and hit send.

Answer (score 0):

Further to bones225's answer earlier: I also found an invisible `div` element works best. However, if you're likely to use this multiple times across your site I would recommend setting the `div` up as a class instead:

```
.anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px; /* adjust this to suit */
}
```

... and then in HTML:

```
<!-- Your link to this item -->
<a href = "#example">Example</a>

<!-- The actual content -->
<div class = "anchor" id = "example"></div>
<h2>Example</h2>
```